# What is the formula for calculation of `R_ij` in `numpy.corrcoef(x, y, rowvar = False)`?

Tags: correlation, pca, scikit-learn, numpy

The manual does not provide the formula if we pass `x` **and** `y`. I do not understand the matrix I get. Here is my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import datasets
    from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    data = iris.data
    centered_data = data - np.mean(data, axis = 0)
    model = PCA()
    transformed_data = model.fit_transform(centered_data)
    centered_transformed_data = transformed_data - np.mean(transformed_data, axis = 0)
    corr = np.corrcoef(centered_data, centered_transformed_data, rowvar = False)
    print(corr.round(2))

centered_data.shape = (150, 4), 
transformed_data.shape = (150, 4)
corr.shape = (8, 8)
```

Please explain what an element of the correlation matrix means.

I would like clarify what I am doing. I need to find a correlation matrix between the initial sample of the data and  the transformed sample of data. Then, I need to find for each feature the principal component that has the highest correlation with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to source code, matrices are just concatenated:
X = np.concatenate((X, y), axis=0)
The result matrix is just a normalized covariance matrix of two concatenated matrices.